# Problem with my shuffle method in Elevens

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, methods, shuffle

I have an assignment for school where I have to make an Elevens card gaming using ArrayLists. I have just recently learned how they work so I am not the best with them. The only problem I am having is with my shuffle method. Here is the code:

```
public void shuffle()
{ 
    while (dealt.size() > 0)
    {
        Card temp = dealt.remove(0);
        undealt.add(temp);
    }

    while (dealt.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * undealt.size());
            Card temp = undealt.remove(random);
            undealt.add(undealt.size(), temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Code you may need to reference:

```
public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values)
{
    undealt = new ArrayList<Card>();
    dealt = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++)
        {
            Card c = new Card(ranks[i], suits[j], values[i]);
            undealt.add(c);
        }
    }
    shuffle();
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use Collections.shuffle()?

Comment: You have many errors in your code.  The second loop in shuffle method cannot process anyting because its condition `dealt.size() > 0` is infeasable - you have emptied `dealt` arraylist before, in the first loop. Try to fix those yourself and you'll get further help.

Comment: @bimjhi I'm sorry I'm really new to Java so a wasn't aware that it was a problem. If I was, I wouldn't have made the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the *shuffle*-method as short as this:

```
public void shuffle() {
    undealt.addAll(dealt);
    dealt.clear();
    Collections.shuffle(undealt);
}
```

---

If you want to pursue your approach, then you need to remove the unnecessary loop in the second part of your *shuffle*-method.

```
public void shuffle() {
    while (dealt.size() > 0) {
        Card temp = dealt.remove(0);
        undealt.add(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * undealt.size());
        Card temp = undealt.remove(random);
        undealt.add(undealt.size(), temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.shuffle()`:

```
public void shuffle() {
    while (dealt.size() > 0)
    {
        Card temp = dealt.remove(0);
        undealt.add(temp);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(undealt); // instead of the second loop
}
```